# How to validate an item exists in a list response in SoapUI?

Tags: rest, groovy, soapui

Short question: In a SoapUI/SoapUI Pro test step, how can I verify that a REST response which is a list contains a specific item?

Long version: I have a test suite that chains together two REST method calls.  First I call `addCustomer`, then I call `getCustomerByPhoneNumber`.  However, phone number is not unique so I may get back a list of several customers.  How can I determine if that list contains the customer I just added?

Example: Say I call `addCustomer` to create `customer2`, and the response returns `customerId = 222`.  I then call `getCustomerByPhoneNumber` and receive the following response.  How do I verify that `customerId = 222` exists in the list?  Ideally I'd also like to verify that all information about `customer2` is correct (phone number, name, etc.)

```
<customers>
    <customer>
        <id>111</id>
        <name>customer1</name>
        <phone>555-5555</phone>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <id>222</id>
        <name>customer2</name>
        <phone>555-5555</phone>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <id>333</id>
        <name>customer3</name>
        <phone>555-5555</phone>
    </customer>
</customers>
```

If the answer requires a Groovy script, I'd appreciate some sample code or psuedocode, since I haven't used Groovy before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use an XQuery assertion on the test step like this:

```
for $customer in //*:customer
where ($customer/id = '222')
return ($customer/name,
        $customer/phone)
```

This produces output like:

```
<name>customer2</name>
<phone>555-5555</phone>
```

Then, in the assertion expected results panel you could substitute the expected values:

```
<name>${customerName}</name>
<phone>${custmerPhone}</phone>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I came to a very similar solution before I saw this answer.  I couldn't figure out how to do it with XPath alone and ended up using an XQuery assertion, with the where clause referencing the ID field of the addCustomer Response.

Answer (score 0):

Using XPath, something like `exists(//*:customer[name[text()='customer2']])`, to see if "he" exists.

Next, something like `//*:customer[name[text()='customer2']]/id` should give you "222".

Comment: And if you want to grab all the info on a customer while knowing lets say id, you could use something like this `/customers/customer/id[text()='222']/..` then you could reference the response xml in the previous teststep in the xpath assertion.